# Have Two Font Awesome Icons Side by Side

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to have two Font Awesome icons side by side, but it's not working.  They're on top of each other.

Here's my code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

I've tried setting my `a` and `i` tags as `display: inline;`

[image]

Comment: If you inspect element on the icons, are there any styles that are being applied to it that are causing them to linebreak?

Comment: if it's wordpress and using their editor don't put line break between them.

Comment: can you put the full code? i tried your code and it work just fine..

Comment: @TemaniAfif that was the issue!  Thanks!

Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using CSS, the above way would be recommended.

However, if you want to do it an easier way using HTML you can do it by using a table

```css
i{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td><td><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```